# Lock accepted answer after few days of being accepted

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can we have lock accepted answer in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) after few days? Just like Lock vote? and unlock if the answer is edited or changed.

For example:

> In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035190/action-after-failed-coded-ui-test/27035581#27035581) the user already accepted my answer *(Nov 20, 2014)* but he unaccepted it *(Nov 26, 2014)* and accept the answer of other user with high reputation even tho he use my answer to his project and useful to him.

**Update:**

If lock accepted answer is not possible.

Why don't just make the answer *"(accepted answer for long time)"* as old answer *(create a mark on it)* if changed to unanswered or unchecked?

Comment: Why would this feature be beneficial?  How would it improve the quality of the site?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Just like in my example... my answer is accepted in Nov 20 and maybe some googler or searcher already search the question and use my answer before Nov 26, and tried to search it again after Nov 26 and they see that the answer is already change. *-(some user don't use the other answer if it's not checked and different from the last time they search )*

Comment: What if the question asker tried your solution, found problems with it in their code over the next few days, then tried the other answer and found it actually worked?

Comment: @MattCoubrough Hmn.. you got a point.

Comment: @Leonel Besides the late discovery of problems that Matt pointed out, people have preferences. A few times I posted an early answer that was 100% correct and accepted, and then was unaccepted in favor of a later answer that the OP preferred for some undisclosed reason. Maybe the other answer was clearer to them, or took them more by the hand than my answer did.

Comment: It's not like your answer was deleted because it was unaccepted. People will still find your answer if they are searching via Google. If it helps other people they will upvote it.

Comment: This feature request seems to serve only one purpose: Giving you your 15 reputation back.

Comment: @meagar Lol, I don't care about 15 rep. Just saying that create an mark for an old accepted answer *(that remove as accepted answer)* but still get the -15 rep if unaccepted.

Answer (score 21):

No. What answer to accept is a choice made by the asker. They should be free to choose any answer they want, if they feel it best answers their question.

If an answer proves to be better than the one they originally accepted, they should be able to accept that at any time.

Don't worry about whether or not your answer is accepted. You should just concentrate on leaving good, helpful answers. That'll always serve you well in the long run.

Comment: How about mark the answer *(know as accepted answer for long time)* as old answer if unaccepted?

Comment: **Slightly Off-topic:** '*What answer to accept is a choice made by the asker. They should be free to choose any answer they want [...]*' - Surely this should remain consistent when voting (up or down) for questions / answers? If I choose to remove a previously up-voted question / answer, I should be able to, no? But currently, it is restricted. I'm personally not for the OP's suggestion but the first sentence made me think of the existing vote-lock.

Comment: @Script47 Regular votes on answers get locked because people used to use voting to strategically push other answers down in the sort order and then remove the votes later to avoid the rep penalty. I'm not sure if voting on questions had similar bad behavior or if it just wasn't deemed worth the effort to have votes work differently on questions than on answers.

Comment: @BSMP ah, right. Did not know that. Thanks for the information.